# Load two images to html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to load two images to my HTML page and position them side by side (Horizontally) using Javascript. But at the first step, a confusion happens.

Here I have a code which results in something like this :

[image]

How can I fix that? Where is my fault?

Javascript:

```
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
  img.setAttribute("src", "1.jpg");
  img.setAttribute("width", "300");
  img.setAttribute("height", "300");
  img.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
  document.body.appendChild(img);

  var img2 = document.createElement("IMG2");
  img2.setAttribute("src", "2.jpg");
  img2.setAttribute("width", "300");
  img2.setAttribute("height", "300");
  img2.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock2");
  document.body.appendChild(img2);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="IMG">
<div id="IMG2">

<script src="Script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
```

CSS:

```
img {

   border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
   padding: 6px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(227, 228, 232), 0 6px 20px 0        rgba(227, 228, 232);  

}


img2 {

   border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
   padding: 6px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(227, 228, 232), 0 6px 20px 0        rgba(227, 228, 232);  

}
```

Comment: What is `<img2 />` element?

Comment: on your img2 you are creating an img2 tag which is wrong

Comment: Yes If I rename them I can see each one loading ...

Comment: You are not NAMING you are literally making a new HTML `<img2 />` and the rendering engine has no clue what an img2 is so it renders it to the best of its ability.

Comment: Thank you guys I got that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your `img2`, you have `var img2 = document.createElement("IMG2");`, which would create an `<img2>` element. This needs to be changed to `var img2 = document.createElement("IMG");` to create an `<img>` element.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.setAttribute("src", "http://placehold.it/100");
img.setAttribute("width", "300");
img.setAttribute("height", "300");
img.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
document.body.appendChild(img);

var img2 = document.createElement("IMG");
img2.setAttribute("src", "http://placehold.it/100");
img2.setAttribute("width", "300");
img2.setAttribute("height", "300");
img2.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock2");
document.body.appendChild(img2);
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(227, 228, 232), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(227, 228, 232);
}

img2 {
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(227, 228, 232), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(227, 228, 232);
}
```

Comment: That Works... 9 Min to accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

You created an element with tag name `img2`. This can't be interpreted by the browser.

So use:

```
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
  img.setAttribute("src", "1.jpg");
  img.setAttribute("width", "300");
  img.setAttribute("height", "300");
  img.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
  document.body.appendChild(img);

  var img2 = document.createElement("IMG");
  img2.setAttribute("src", "2.jpg");
  img2.setAttribute("width", "300");
  img2.setAttribute("height", "300");
  img2.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock2");
  document.body.appendChild(img2);
```

And simply ignore the css `img2{...}`

Comment: Thank you... I got that

Answer (score 2):

Just change the `img2` to `img`

```
document.createElement("IMG2")
```

To

```
document.createElement("img")
```

Because `.createElement` is creating an img2 tag which is not a valid HTML tag.